# How to implement the alias for a step function in Serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

In my project, I'm using `serverless-aws-alias` alongside `serverless` to deploy my code and everything to AWS. I have lambda functions which are aliased for `dev` and `prod` versions. Each time I make a change, I would first use the serverless command prompt tool to deploy a `dev` version and make sure that everything is fine before I use the same tool to deploy the `prod` version.

This works all fine (more or less) but when I tried to include a step function definition in my `serverless.yml` file, I faced a limitation. While lambda functions can have versions and aliases in AWS, step functions do not have such functionality. So far, I've tested this (which is a fail):

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStepFunction:
      name: MyStepFunction-${opt:alias}
      .
      .
      .
```

While this does create a step function like `MyStepFunction-dev` but the problem with it is that as soon as I create the `prod` version, it will delete the `dev` version (the serverless assumes I'm renaming the step function). Even worse, if I create the `dev` version, it will delete the `prod` version which of course is unacceptable.

Does anyone know how I can have two step functions, one for `dev` and one for `prod`, implemented with one single definition in my `serverless.yml`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your actual question, and I don't fully understand the context for what you're doing, but in case it's useful -- you can have a single step function run different Lambda aliases. It doesn't seem to be very well documented, but it's described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html. You configure `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke"` and then pass `Qualifier` in `Parameters`. So you can give `Qualifier` a value from the step function input payload, for example. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up implementing this (not necessarily the best solution for everyone):

I split my `serverless.yml` file into two files. I kept my lambda function definitions in one file and then moved the step function definitions into a separate file. Of course, the serverless framework does not let you rename the `serverless.yml` file which means the two files I just mentioned cannot coexist in the same folder at the same time.

My lambda function yaml file would look like this:

```
service:                      Lambda-Functions

provider:
  name:                       aws
  stage:                      ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

plugins:
- serverless-aws-alias
- serverless-pseudo-parameters

functions:
  func1:
    name:                     func1
    handler:                  src/func1.handler
    environment:
      STEP_FUNCTIONS_ARN:     arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:MyStepFunction-${opt:alias}
```

And I'll deploy it this way:

```
$ sls deploy --stage dev --alias dev
$ sls deploy --stage dev --alias prod
```

The other yaml file (for step functions) would look like this:

```
service:                 Step-Functions

provider:
  name:                  aws
  stage:                 ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

plugins:
- serverless-step-functions
- serverless-pseudo-parameters

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStepFunction:
      name:              MyStepFunction-${opt:stage}
        definition:
          StartAt:       StartState
          States:
            StartState:
              Type:      Task
              Resource:  arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:some-func:${opt:stage}
              Next:      SomeState
```

And I'll deploy it like this:

```
$ sls deploy --stage dev
$ sls deploy --stage prod
```

I'm not saying that this is flawless but it works. In the example given above, the `func1` is supposed to instantiate an instance of the step function `MyStepFunction` that's why it needs the step function's ARN.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using aliases like this, I would suggest taking advantage of the "stages" in Serverless.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'} # Set the default stage used. Default is dev
```

Then as far as naming your step function it would be something like:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStepFunction:
      name: MyStepFunction-${opt:stage}
```

Then when you deploy it would be something like `sls deploy --stage dev` or `sls deploy --stage prod`. This will utilize two different stacks and you won't run into stuff getting deleted because it thinks you renamed it!

Comment: Thanks. While your input does help me with understanding the difference between stage and alias, but it's not going to work in this case. I do need to have two aliases within a single stage. And two stages do not work as two aliases as far as lambda functions are concerned. In other words, if I use stages as you mentioned, I'll be facing another problem with the lambda functions.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't fully grasp what you are trying to accomplish then. You should be able to add a second step function as long as under state machines you use a key like MyStepFunction2 under that a name of MyStepFunction-prod and also hard code the dev named one as well. It'd deploy both in each case but I'm not sure how to get around that. If you tell me more about your case I can try to help in more detail, also happy to pair on this if you'd like.

Comment: It's simple, I'm trying to implement the same concept of "aliases" for step functions. Assume a step function which has two versions, dev and prod. If you run the dev version, it will call all the dev version of lambda functions. And if you call its prod version, the prod version of the lambda functions will be called. But since step functions do not support aliases, I have to craete two step functions. And of course, these two step functions should coexist.

Comment: I can implement this manually (without serverless) by creating two setp functions but I'm trying to use serverless for my CI.

Comment: I think https://github.com/HyperBrain/serverless-aws-alias/blob/master/README.md#use-with-per-alias-resources contains you answer. But it's not supported by the actual framework right now.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure about that. The given link says that the problem we have right now is that serverless "does not support variable substitution in property names". But in fact, that's not true. As I've shown in my example, the subsitution does happen right now and that's not the problem. The problem is that the newly named resource deletes the old one. I'm confused about the claim in that passage!

Comment: It does not support it in the resource key names. The thing you are doing manually right now, which means the alias plugin cannot manage the per alias private resources without them being deleted. It's exactly the problem you are having if i understand correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184819/discussion-between-mehran-and-jared-short).